# Translation from the English Apex Predator?

Tags: motto

I am doing a project for a logo that intends to use the Latin translation for the term "Apex Predator". From the various web sites if have visited it appears that "Apicem Rapax" is one possible translation. Would like to ask if you can confirm this or provide a more appropriate translation.

Comment: That literally means 'a rapacious man [is doing something to] the summit'. :p

Comment: Does the person who asked this question work for 5.11 tactical? I made a purchase several months ago that came with a patch of a saber tooth tiger skeleton that’s says “apicem rapax” underneath..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My suggestion is ***praedator summus***.
The word *summus* means "highest", "top", "peak", "last", "supreme", "most important", and similar things.
See [Lewis and Short (*superus* III.C)](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=superus&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) for details.

An apex predator is the last one in a food chain and at the top of the ecological structure.
I find *summus* to be a good description of this situation, and it also parallels the literal meaning of "apex" (basic meaning: *summus* = "highest").

While [*apex*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=apex&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) is a Latin noun, I find it more natural to use an adjective than a noun here.

Answer (score 10):

*Apex* is a noun, and Latin cannot, unlike English, use nouns as adjectives. I don't know if there was a set phrase for this term, though I doubt it.

*Praedator* is where we get the word 'predator' from, and like the English, it can mean "hunter."

Apex is a metaphorical word for "top," so I'd suggest something like:

***Praedator primus***

*Primus* means "first," but it's often used to mean "best" or "top" or even "greatest," with emphasis on primacy. The chief centurion, for example, of a Roman legion was the *primus pilus*.